# Convert HEX to BIGINT (or its string representation) - SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ipv6

I'm trying to convert a `HEX` value (ipv6 address, expanded) to a `BIGINT` value on SQL Server 2019.

- Input is: `2a0085c0000100000000000002410023`
- Expected output: `55830288595252163998698714105846497315`

Tried pretty much every solution that was marked as 'working' on SO and everywhere else, for instance:

```
select 
    convert(bigint, convert(varbinary, '2a0085c0000100000000000002410023', 2))
```

but to no avail. Previous query results in this output: `37814307`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The maximum a `BIGINT` can hold is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (19 digits) and your expected output has **twice** the number of digits (38)...... - [MS docs on integer-based datatypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Furthermore: your `CONVERT` is flawed - if you **do not** specify an explicit **length** for the `varbinary` - it defaults to 30 bytes - which is most likely not enough to hold your data..... you need to **explicitly define** a length for the `varbinary` in the `CONVERT` !!

Comment: Why do you need to convert/store the value as an integer? The proper type for a binary value is binary or varbinary.

Comment: @Dan Guzman: I need the conversion to a representation of the decimal value for geolocation purposes.

Comment: @marc_s, actually, it is 39 decimal digits: `0` to `340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455`.

Comment: @marc_s, that is not my point, and I accept the limits you quote. My point is that your statement, "_your expected output has twice the number of digits (38)_" is actually one digit short for IPv6 addressing in decimal. There are 128 bits in an IPv6 address, which means that the range is what I explained in my comment, and that is up to 39 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

`bigint` is too small (64 bits) to fit an IPv6 address (128 bits).

You can get the two halves like this:

```sql
SELECT
    high = CAST(SUBSTRING(ipv6Val, 1, 8) AS bigint),
    low = CAST(SUBSTRING(ipv6Val, 9, 8) AS bigint)
```

This **assumes** the `varbinary/binary` value is actually the exact length of 16 bytes.

---

*EDIT based on comment*

IPv6 is commonly represented as ***hex*** not ***decimal***, this will get it as text:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), ipv6Val, 2)
```

Converting to decimal is really difficult in T-SQL, as in most languages, and I beg to ask why you would ever need it, given IPv6 is never used that way.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not need to store the value, I need a representation of its decimal value for geolocation purposes

Comment: IPv6 uses hex not decimal. Which API do you have that demands decimal?

Comment: the databases of ip2location store the location for an ip range, and that range is in decimal form, whether it is for v4 or v6

Comment: Indeed, that's pretty bad. Is this a DB that you download? Then I would **strongly** consider converting it the other way. Incidentally how up to date is that, IPs change by the minute.

Comment: It's a monthly download, yes. I suppose I would stumble upon the same sort of conversion problems if I decided to convert the existing data into another format, so I guess I'm stuck. Can't believe though that ipv6 has been around for years and so little seems to exist to work with it...

Comment: IPv6 is stored as hex *everywhere* I've ever seen, often formatted with `:` between every 2 bytes (4 hex characters). I've never seen it as decimal, it's really unusual and difficult to work with such large decimals. A 16 byte binary is a doddle.